# Add ext4 support to mkfs

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, filesystem, format, ext4

I got a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS:

```
# uname -a
Linux host.xyz 3.13.0-042stab123.9 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 13:01:59 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The kernel itself seems to support ext4:

```
# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   cgroup
nodev   devpts
nodev   mqueue
        ext4
nodev   nfs
nodev   nfs4
nodev   delayfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   sysfs
nodev   proc
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   binfmt_misc
nodev   fusectl
nodev   fuse
nodev   rpc_pipefs
```

But `mkfs` does not:

```
# mkfs.
mkfs.bfs     mkfs.cramfs  mkfs.minix
```

I would like to format a partition as ext4 but apparently, the preinstalled image does not include the required executable. Is there any way to install it? If there is not, what is my best option?

Comment: Install e2fsprogs with apt-get

Comment: @TomYan Thank you so much, I have been trying to find the correct package for hours! If you write an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: As noted, [`mkfs.ex4` is in `e2fsprogs`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mkfs.ext4&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)